# Having 2 consecutive divs, the second one is overlapping the first one in mobile

Tags: html, css

I'm having a problem in the mobile version of my desktop. It's an edited versione of the classic theme for prestashop 1.7.6. [Here](https://alto.7180.eu)'s a link to the website.

In the footer, I have 2 consecutive divs, each one with its content. The first div has the **block_myaccount_infos** ID, the second one has the **block-contact** class.

The first div has a custom JS which should display the dropdown content, similar to the two sections before that. Since I noticed that the JS wasn't being executed, I used the chrome inspector tool, and I found out that the second div is overlapping the first one.

[image]

I tested adding a  tag inbetween, which works, but it's not a valid solution to me since i need the two divs to be on the same line in the desktop version.

Comment: I tried both on firefox and chrome but couldn't replicate the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have

```
@media (max-width: 1025px)
#footer #block_myaccount_infos {
    width: 34%;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
```

in your css. The issue is caused by that `float: left;`

If you alter or removed that and the `<br>` in your HTML, it should fix your issue. Hope that helps.

Comment: I did some trick with the css and the br, not beautiful coding, but it works.
I still thank you for your help!